# Increment with timer.Tick not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a metronome project set up. I have a tap button which should check the tempo of your beat and average it out. Every bit of math works properly because I checked it with a calculator. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace Metronome
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Convert tempo to timer1.Tick (miliseconds between each beat)
            timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(60000 / numericUpDown1.Value);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Play / Pause button
            if (button1.Text == "Go!") { timer1.Enabled = true; button1.Text = "Stop!"; }
            else if (button1.Text == "Stop!") { timer1.Enabled = false; button1.Text = "Go!"; }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The 'ding' sound for the metronome
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();        
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the tempo to be the average of the convertion from miliseconds between 2 beats and the current tempo
            if (timer2.Enabled) { numericUpDown1.Value = ((60000 / Tap) + numericUpDown1.Value) / 2; Tap = 0; }
            else timer2.Enabled = true;
        }

        int Tap = 0;
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the amount of miliseconds between each beat
            Tap++;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Reset the tap timer
            timer2.Enabled = false;
            Tap = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in timer2_Tick, because it should add 1 to Tap every milisecond, instead, when I tried it it goes to a tiny number like 20 or 30. How can I fix this?

Comment: The Timer doesn't have millisecond resolution. It has a resolution of ~15 ms. Which would explain the values you're getting.

Comment: So can I change timer2.Interval to 15 and replace (60000 / Tap) with (4000 / Tap)? The interval has to be as small as possible to prevent bugs

Comment: That might work, but it isn't guaranteed. Windows is a multi-user operating system. Other threads can interrupt execution of your thread, effectively delaying the tick events raised by your timer. You get a best-effort attempt at the requested resolution. Bugs are inevitable if you do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to check the amount of time passed between button taps, use a `StopWatch`. It gives you a high precision timing mechanism. There is no need for you to count milliseconds yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good article I always rely on when selecting which timer to use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

I would suggest using one of the threaded options.  Specifically, the article says of the the windows forms timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`):

> If you're looking for a metronome, you've come to the wrong place.

Comment: roryap is correct.  `SWF.Timer` will only fire when the UI thread is active. You really want to use `System.Threading.Timer` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx5easy.aspx)

Comment: It worked, but took up lots of code, so I instead changed it to be the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch so that I don't have to spend time figuring it out. Thanks anyway